# how can I query where clause from json

Tags: c#, json, linq-to-objects

I am trying to return the json part from my json query where a certain property has a value. Code:

```
  class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            go();
        }

        public static void go()
        {
            string json = @"{
    'rows': [
        {
            'country': 'UK',
            'description': 'this is a desc',
            'gezien': true,
            'Count': 3,
            'url': 'een/twee',
            'stam': 'blabla',
            'kanaal': 'NOS'
        },
        {
            'url': 'drie/vier',
            'stam': 'divers',
            'Count': 1,
            'kanaal': 'SRV'
        }

    ],
    'skip': 0,
    'take': 10,
    'total': 100
}";
            JObject jObj = JObject.Parse(json);
            var url = (string)jObj.Descendants()
                        .OfType<JProperty>()
                        .Where(p => p.Count > 2)
                        .First()
                        .Value;


            Console.WriteLine(url);
        }


    }
```

I am trying to return the rows that have Count>2 but receiving this error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Core.dll
```

Comment: Did you try setting breakpoints and stepping through? It might help to inspect values in each step and see where exactly is the exception thrown.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
var url = jObj.SelectToken("rows")
              .Where(t => t["Count"].Value<int>() > 2)
              .First()["url"].Value<string>();
```

Answer (score 0):

all the jproperties are of length 1.

Your error is from

```
.Where(p => p.Count > 2).First()  // same as First(p => p.Count > 2)
```